# Error after launching new deployed application in GlassFish

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

I have deployed an app successfully, but now it is saying that

> If the server or listener is not running, the link may not work. In this event, check the status of the server instance. After launching the web application, use the browser's Back button to return to this screen.

What could be a problem?

**UPDATE**
It is giving the error:

> com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /index.xhtml Not
>   Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Comment: Is this something that is in the log file (or console), or is it displayed in the web browser?

Comment: it is displaying in the web browser.

Comment: What is the URL you're accessing?

Comment: I am launching application from the list in deployed aplciations from glassfish.

Comment: Is there any message in the Glassfish log?

Comment: Can you update the question with you `web.xml`?